# FBO Depth texture visualization issues

Tags: opengl, glsl

I switched from render buffer to depth texture in my FBO.But it seem like it doesn't contain any depth data.If I render this texture to a full screen quad everything is black.I am pretty sure the texture and FBO setup is ok.FBO is completed and if I clear depth, let's say to gray :

glClearDepth(0.5f);

Then I see the color in the blit pass, but not the data from the geometry rendering.

Anyway, that is how I create the texture:

```
                glBindTexture   ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, _id );
            glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,intFmt,theWidth,theHeight);          
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
        glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
        glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY);   


        glBindTexture(_target,0);
```

Where intFmt is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 or GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32 (tried both..)

That is how I attach it to the FBO:

```
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _id);
     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, target,_id, 0);
```

And this is blit pass fragment shader:

```
#version 420 
layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D COLOR_MAP_0;
smooth in vec2 uvsOut;
out vec4 OUTPUT;

void main(void) {

    ivec2 tsize = textureSize(COLOR_MAP_0, 0);
    vec2 screntc = gl_FragCoord.xy * (1.0 / vec2(tsize));
    OUTPUT =  vec4(texture(COLOR_MAP_0, screntc).rrr   ,1) ;

}
```

Maybe I should explicitly write depth in fragment shader?

I tried to linearize the depth in the blit fragment shader.It works.Now I can see the depth.But I see white and some gray shades without it.In the snapshot:left part is drawn using linearization while the right part samples from depth texture directly.
[image]

Comment: How are you displaying your depth texture to verify data? What are near and far clipping planes and distance to geometry you're drawing?

Comment: Near is 0.1 ,far 10000 .Distance to geometry is between 0 to 1000.For display depth I just bind depth texture, draw full screen quad using frag shader mentioned above.

Comment: I don't see anything too wrong with code you've presented. So wrong part is missing. Have you checked that glGetError() is 0 and are you sure your geometry/view matrices are correct?

Comment: I am running GL debug extension so getting all the errors right into console.Everything is ok with it.But please see my update.

Comment: By 'linearize' you mean normalization?

Comment: No, I mean this : http://www.geeks3d.com/20091216/geexlab-how-to-visualize-the-depth-buffer-in-glsl/

Comment: Well, actually it _is_ normalization. Try using texture2D function in shader instead of texture, i think this one is too smart.

Comment: Bah, my mistake, sorry. Haven't used it for quite a time. If your depth texture is used as `sampler2D`, you getting actual non-normalized depth value. If it is `sampler2DShadow`, you getting normalized values (the ones you calling 'linearized'). Make sure your depth texture comparison function is GL_NONE (it is in your example - so ok).

Comment: Everything is black in this case.

Comment: Have you tried moving your camera really close to the geometry? You should see something in the right part of the screen. It is totally normal that 80% of the (normalized) raw depth is between 0.99 and 1.0 which results in a white image.

Comment: Meh. Sorry again, 5 years out if graphics. sampler2DShadow is indeed logical operation available only when depth comparison is enabled. On a contrary, sampler2D available only when comparison is disabled. Without knowing your actual projection matrix and geometry it's hard to tell anything, but i assume these results are exactly your clip space depth. Article you've referenced to is just making them more 'visible'.

Comment: `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` is deprecated. In GLSL 130 (OpenGL 3.0), any sampler2D that has a depth texture bound to it will always return `vec4 (r, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` irrespective of how you set `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE`. In fact, if you try to use this enum in a 3.2+ core context it should be giving you an invalid enum error. This is not your problem, but I figured I should point this out.

Comment: What would be more important in answering this question, would be the actual implementation of the shaders you are using to blit the depth texture on the left and right side of the screen. It is also worth mentioning that if you do not call `glViewport (...)` to re-define the viewport for the blit on the right/left halves of the screen, then using `gl_FragCoords.xy` to compute your texture coordinates is not going to result in the same image on the right and left side of the screen. You may be sampling depth texels out of range and wrapping (edge clamp) could explain the solid white color.

Comment: @keltar indeed,if I move the camera just a couple of steps back and forth then I see color change,but it happens really in a very narrow range.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman - I use the same frag shader as shown here : http://www.geeks3d.com/20091216/geexlab-how-to-visualize-the-depth-buffer-in-glsl/   I don't use different viewports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems okay and normal.

You have to keep in mind that DEPTH is not an RGB data nor it's linear, the actual format depends on what you request ( in the OpenGL context creation ) or the buffer/texture you create for the FBO.
DEPTH is always a single channel data however the fragment shader allows you to access however you want .rgb will return data but it'll be incorrect.

The DEPTH data since it's non linear you can think of it as the information is compressed into the closer part to 1.0 so most of the things have values of 0.9998 0.9997, if you you can see the difference in image editor apps but again it's not the way how it should be displayed after all.

To display the DEPTH you need to linearize it so it "makes sense" for that you need to take the near/far plane into account, in that case White == far , Dark ( Black ) == close.

Comment: Ok,I see,but how do you explain that in many demos,even like this : http://www.geeks3d.com/20091216/geexlab-how-to-visualize-the-depth-buffer-in-glsl/   they still are able too present non - linearized depth buffer?

Comment: Well you can or can't see it, depends on circumstances as you can see here : https://db.tt/HKrg2TOx if you are far enough it looks like its not there altho turning down the brightness by a fair amount it becomes visible. This is the example of how non-display compatible data behaves when you try to display it. You normally display with 24bit unsigned chars, the depth buffer is at least 16 bit floating point so OpenGL will down convert it so it can be displayed and this is the result. So long story short you can create such circumstances that it seems that you can display the raw depth buffer.